# Memory model of the Adreno GPU

Tags: gpu, gpgpu

Reading about Adreno GPU by Qualcomm being an **SOC** I have come up with a question that is the memory same for both of them?

If yes, is there some virtual addressing on top of of it like CUDA's Unified Virtual Addressing (UVA) ?

Also, if this is not the case is there something like the CUDA 6's unified memory model supported in here?

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be best if you rephrased your question due to it being ambiguous. As far as understand your question, you would like to know if Adreno GPUs have any unified memory support and unified virtual addressing support.

Starting with the basics, CUDA is Nvidia only paradigm and Adreno's use OpenCL instead. OpenCL version 2.0 specification has a support for unified memory with the name shared virtual memory (SVM). Section 3.3.3 in the specification explains how it works and the constraints https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/specs/opencl-2.0.pdf. I don't have extensive knowledge about how CUDA's UVA and unified memory model works, but in OpenCL you have different capabilities from coarse grain support to fine grain system support. You need to check the whitepaper of the Adreno GPU you want to learn about which one is supported.

Nevertheless, according to Adreno wikipedia page, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adreno, 5th generation Adreno GPUs have full OpenCL 2.0 support, which should enable at least coarse grain SVM support. Older Adreno GPUs do not support sharing any address space pointers, so you need to copy the data between CPU and GPU address spaces or use pinned memory.